# Having a little difficulty with adding frames to my program

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to work on changing the layout of my program but I'm having difficulty adding in frames and in turn widgets into those frames. Partly because I don't fully understand the code I have written below, yet. I have indicated the parts I need help understanding from a frame perspective with a *.

The problem I am having is that I would like to split my screen in half width ways so that the top half of the window displays as a red and the bottom blue. To do this I have packed the side in as TOP and BOTTOM respectively; however, there is white space between them. How can I remove this?

Thank you,

```
class The99club (Tk):

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):

        Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        Tk.title(self, 'The 99 Club')

        container = Frame(self)

        container.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky='nsew')*
        container.grid_rowconfigure (2,weight = 1)*
        container.grid_columnconfigure (2,weight = 1)*

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage,PageOne,PageTwo,PageThree,PageFour,PageFive):

            frame = F (container,self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')*


        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame (self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.top_frame = Frame(self, bg = 'red')
        self.top_frame.pack(side = TOP, fill= X)
        self.bottom_frame = Frame (self, bg = 'blue')
        self.bottom_frame.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = X)

        label = Label(self.top_frame, text = 'Welcome to The 99 Club', bg = '#66B132',fg='yellow', font = ('Agent Red',30))
        label.pack()

        label2 = Label(self.top_frame, text = 'Press Enter to begin.',bg = '#66B132',fg='yellow',font = ('Comic Sans MS',24))
        label2.pack()
        self.button = Button(self, text = 'Enter',bg = 'yellow',command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne),font = ('Comic Sans MS', 24),relief = SUNKEN)
        self.button.pack()
```

Comment: Can you please try to upload a code which shows the problem and can be run on another machine. Then, we could help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you probably didn't realise, but the whitespace is actually the border of your frame. To remove it, you have to set the `borderwidth`=0 and `highlightthickness`=0 in the parameters of your frame. So, it would look like:

```
self.top_frame = Frame(self, bg = 'red', borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Esthita, thank you for your suggestion but sadly it hasn't worked. There is still whitespace between the red and blue border.